# @Controller Spring для множества пользователей

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet, controller

Пишу веб-приложение в учебных целях в котором присутствует авторизация пользователей, и далее, для авторизованного пользователя доступна некоторая логика (добавлять элементы, удалять их из обычного List).

Использую Spring fraemwork и аннотацию Controller для создания, непосредственно, контроллеров. **Вопрос в следующем**:

Если сразу несколько пользователей обращаются к моему сервису, то как происходит обработка этих запросов контроллером? На каждого пользователя создается свой контроллер, и то есть для каждого пользователя будет создан уникальный ArrayList и доступа к нему (изменению) у других пользователей не будет? (Понимаю, что маловероятно, потому что для большого количества пользователей не хватит никакой оперативной памяти)

Или же один контроллер может обрабатывать сразу запросы нескольких пользователей? И тогда несколько пользователей будут редактировать один и тот же объект? И если так, то как в этом случае лучше поступить? Создавать Map>? Или есть другие более правильные способы?

В интернете особо информации по этому вопросу не нашел.

Comment: Вам надо почитать: 1) о времени жизни объектов в Spring 2) о хранении состояния в веб приложениях

Comment: @tym32167, представление о времени жизни имею, знаю, что все контроллеры синглтоны. И как хранится состояние тоже более менее представляю. Тут скорее актуальна больше вторая часть вопроса, на тему: "как правильнее это сделать?"  Но спасибо за направление.

Comment: сделать что? Вы ж ничего не описали в вопросе

Comment: @tym32167, сделать верную архитектуру приложения с правильной изоляцией объектов для разных пользователей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю из вашего вопроса вы интересуетесь тем можно хранить какую либо информацию (состояние) для каждого пользователя отдельно.

По умолчанию все компоненты (@Controller/@Service/@Component) являются Singleton и при обращении к ним создаются в единственном экземпляре. И все запросы пользователей будут адресоваться к экземплярам одного и того же объекта.

Однако объекты модели с которыми взаимодействуют контроллеры вполне могут быть уникальными для каждого пользователя так как в Spring есть штатная возможность работы на уровне сессий. Для этого можно обратится к аннотации @SessionAttributes. Пример использования можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-session-attributes).

В этом случае вам не придется создавать по контроллеру на каждого пользователя, а объекты будут привязаны к сессии - то есть будут уничтожены итерацией gc после завершения сессии то есть их время жизни более менее будет сопоставимо с самой сессией.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Это как раз то, что подразумевалось.

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию в Spring все компоненты синглетоны - классы имею единственный экземпляр в течении всей жизни программы и загружаются они во время запуска приложения. Поэтому по умолчанию единственный экземпляр компонента обрабатывает запросы от всех пользователей. Можно задать компоненту @Scope("prototype"), тогда при каждом обращении будет создаваться новый экземпляр компонента.

Через компоненты вы редактируете сущности а не компоненты. Два пользователя не должны редактировать одну сущность - это больше вопрос к уровням изоляции транзакций.

Возможно не совсем понятен ваш вопрос. Какую конкретную задачу вы хотите решить?

Comment: Задача состоит в том, чтобы не создавать для каждого пользователя свой собственный контроллер, а обойтись созданием "уникального" объекта List<> для каждого пользователя, чтобы разные пользователи никак не влияли друг на друга.

В ответе выше достаточно полно описывается необходимое решение.

Comment: А для Prototype будет создано слишком много контроллеров для большого числа пользователей, что неоправданно по использованию памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже выше отмечали, Controller создается в единственном числе. В случае когда несколько запросов поступают в контроллер, то сервер приложение (Например, Tomcat) создает для каждого клиентского запроса отдельный поток. Таким образом в контролер заходят столько потоков, сколько клиентских запросов существует. Иными словами, контроллер используется параллельно в многопоточном режиме. Поэтому рекомендуется делать такие класс "без состояния" - без переменных класса. Вы упоминали List<>. Не знаю для чего, но если вы хотите хранить там что-то между запросами, сделав его полем класса, то это не хорошая идея. Больше инфы от вас даст больше ответа